# I'm making a discord bot and want it to DM a user

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I'm making a kick command for my discord bot and I want the bot to DM the user telling them they have been kicked. So far I have got:

```
    case 'kick':
        const Embed = new
    Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Success!')
        .setColor(0x00FF00)
        .setDescription(`Successfully kicked **${args[2]}** \n \n**Message:** \n"${args.join(' ')}"`)

        if(!message.member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS'])) return message.channel.send('*Error: You do not have permission to use* **kick**.');
        if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send('*Error: Please specify a user to kick!*');

        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        member.kick().then((member) => {
            message.channel.send(Embed);
        })
    break;
```

So far, the user is successfully kicked so all this works.

All I need to know is how to make the bot DM the mentioned user to tell them they have been kicked. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for this method: [GuildMember#send()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=send)

```
member.send("Your DM Here");
```

Note that if the only reason your bot could send a member DMs was because of a mutual server in which the user had DMs from server members enabled (user disabled other types of stranger DMs), then your bot would not be able to send the DM. It would probably be a good idea to send them the DM and wait for the method's returned promise to resolve before kicking them, for a higher chance that the DM actually reaches them.